# Is there a way to have landscape orientation on an Activity without requiring the device support landscape mode?

Tags: android

Basically I added an `Activity` with `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` but it is an `Activity` that will be used very little and it isn't critical at all. If it fails it fails and it doesn't matter.

I added this to my manifest:

`<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.LANDSCAPE" android:required="false"/>`

And it didn't make a difference. The Play Store is still removing support for a handful of devices when I upload a new APK.

Is there some way I can do this without leaving those devices behind?

Comment: [The documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element?hl=en#screen-hw-features) shows that as `android.hardware.screen.landscape`, not `android.hardware.screen.LANDSCAPE`.

Comment: That was it, thank you. Feel free to make it into an answer so I can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most things in Android are case-sensitive, and that includes the value of `android:name` for `<uses-feature>`. Use `android.hardware.screen.landscape`, not `android.hardware.screen.LANDSCAPE`.